# How do I find where the merge conflict is in a big file?

Tags: git, git-merge, conflict, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I have a file that has 6000 lines and have scanned it over and over again but do not see the merge conflict. How else can I find it?

Comment: `<file.txt grep -nF '>>>>'` should give you the line numbers of lines containing `>>>>` you can do the same with `====` and `<<<<`. There's also `git mergetool` which will pick a merge utility somehow ... I don't know the exact details.

Comment: when i'm doing git pull, how can I see which branch my locate is pulling from?

Comment: It should be pulling from the remote named `origin` and the matching branch by default. I think...

Comment: `/^<<<<<` ...  you are using `vi` aren't you?

Answer (score 3):

Just search for their markers, like =======, <<<<<<<, or >>>>>>>

It will look like:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:file.txt
Hello world
=======
Goodbye
>>>>>>> 77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086:file.txt
```

Comment: I also recommend setting `merge.conflictstyle` to `diff3` so that you get the `|||||||` marker and the base version, as well as the `<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>>` markers around the local/`--ours` and other/`--theirs` versions.

Answer (score 3):

You can always try using

```
 git mergetool
```

For me, this will launch BeyondCompare for each file that has conflicts, which shows both files used in the merge and the conflicts that you can easily resolve. What it launches depends on the diff tool that you have.